# SQL Server Query Case When With Full Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, case-when

I'm trying to create a script. That script is going to declare a variable with trigger word and after that i need to run one of the queries depends on the trigger word and return all of the results, like:

```
DECLARE @name varchar(50)
set @name = 'value from the script'

select 
    case 
       when @name = 'orders' then (select * from orders)
       when @name = 'sales' then (select * from sales)
      ..etc
    end
```

But this causes an error since I'm trying to run a full query with more than 1 row of results. I'm stuck here. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `if`:

```
declare @name varchar(50);
set @name = 'value from the script';

if @name = 'orders' 
begin;
  select * from orders;
end;

if @name = 'sales' 
begin;
  select * from sales;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare a variable and assign the query to the variable.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(50)
set @name = 'value from the script'
DECLARE @MyQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

select 
    @MyQuery = CASE 
                    WHEN @name = 'orders' then 'select * from orders'
                    WHEN @name = 'sales' then 'select * from sales' 
                    ELSE 'SELECT 1' END

EXECUTE sp_executesql @MyQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)

SET @name = 'value from the script'
IF ( @name = 'orders' )
    ( SELECT * FROM orders )
ELSE IF ( @name = 'sales' )
    ( SELECT * FROM sales )
```